# Hydrodynamics on cellular automata (FHP, etc)

Tags: physics, simulation, cellular-automata, fluid-dynamics

I am looking for CA-based fluid dynamics software like this [Implementation of FHP model in Nvidia CUDA technology](http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/~sebastian.szkoda/msc.html), but still no luck.

I want to "play" with those simulations myself and at least read some related papers. It is even better, if software is open-source.

Answer (score 2):

A few papers can be found over here

- [Using Cellular Automata for porous media simulation](http://www.ssdonline.sscc.ru/o-l/supercomputing.pdf)
- [Synchronous versus Asynchronous Cellular Automata for Simulating Nano-Systems Kinetics](http://www.ssdonline.sscc.ru/o-l/syn-asyn.pdf)

And a presentation from the same group:

- [Cellular Automata on GPU](http://ssdonline.sscc.ru/kalgin/cuda/ca.gpu.pdf) (in Russian)
- [Homepage of Konstantin Kalgin](http://ssdonline.sscc.ru/kalgin/): Parallel simulation of asynchronous Cellular Automata evolution

Comment: Thank you! And what about software (except Russian "CA on GPU" group)?

Comment: Not sure if this group has any software available for download, but sources are probably available on request.